# Parse json object to column in linux

Tags: bash, awk, sed, jq

I have a output of json format as below

```
{
"ip": "0.0.0.0",
"hostname": "No Hostname",
"city": "Beijing",
"region": "Beijing Shi",
"country": "CN",
"loc": "39.9289,116.3883",
"org": "AS55967 Beijing Baidu Netcom Science and Technology Co., Ltd."
}
```

i need values of country and city as below

```
CN        Beijing
```

i have used below jq command and sed command to display country but dont know how to display city as another column.

**jq**

```
 curl  -s ipinfo.io/0.0.0.0 | jq '.country'
```

**sed**

```
 curl  -s ipinfo.io/0.0.0.0 | sed '/country/!d' | sed s/\"country\":\ //g | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\,//g'
```

The output of this country and city columns should be added to 4th & 5th column of another csv file sample below

```
2016-03-29 00:05:23 0.0.0.0 CN Beijing 10.0.0.197 
2016-03-29 00:56:37 1.1.1.1 FR France 10.0.1.117
2016-03-29 00:57:20 2.2.2.2 FR France 10.0.0.197
```

Comment: `jq -j '.country, " ", .city, "\n"'`? Then `paste other_file jq_output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl  -s ipinfo.io/0.0.0.0 | jq -r '.country +"\t"+  .city'
```

Comment: Consider using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-\%28foo%29) instead. It'll be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\": \""; OFS="\t" }
{ gsub(/^"|",$/,""); f[$1] = $2 }
/}/ { print f["country"], f["city"]; delete f }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
CN      Beijing
```

Since you didn't provide the "other file" to add the output of this to or provide any details on how you want to do that, it's not clear what you want to do with that so it's left to you...

Comment: Thanks Ed, it helped too

Answer (score 0):

You can first put to two fields you're interested in into an array:

```
$ curl -s ipinfo.io | jq '[.country, .city]'
[
  "US",
  "Mountain View"
]
```

And then convert to csv with `@csv`:

```
$ curl -s ipinfo.io | jq '[.country, .city] | @csv'
"\"US\",\"Mountain View\""
```

The `-r` (raw) argument cleans up some of that escaping:

```
$ curl -s ipinfo.io | jq -r '[.country, .city] | @csv'
"US","Mountain View"
```

You can then use `paste` to combine the output with another file.